# Regex match shortest string

Tags: regex, perl

If I have string

`zeta alpha alpha beta charlie delta`

How can I extract `alpha beta`?

If i use `alpha(.+?)beta`, it will return `alpha alpha beta` instead.

Comment: So for `alpha charlie beta alpha beta` you want it to return `alpha beta`?  I.e. the shortest match *anywhere* in the string?

Comment: Is there any reason you are discarding `/alpha beta/`? Or `/alpha\s+beta/`? Perhaps you should explain that part first.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
alpha(?:(?!\balpha\b).)*?beta
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qY9dI5/3)

- `alpha` Matches the string `alpha`
- `(?:(?!\balpha\b).)*?` will do a non-greedy match of any character but not of `alpha`, zero or more times. `\b` word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.
- `beta` matches the string `beta`

Comment: This produces `alpha charlie beta` on `alpha charlie beta alpha beta`.

Comment: yep it does. That's what op asked.

Comment: The OP asked for the shortest matching string -- that would be `alpha beta` in this example.

Comment: no, he doesn't mean this. Let's wait for the op's reply.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that there's more to this question, but how about

```
/(alpha\s+beta)/
```

If you want the *last* `alpha` that has a following `beta` up to the first `beta` then

```
/.*(alpha.+?beta)/
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my $re = qr/(alpha(?:(?!alpha).)*?beta)/;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @res = $_ =~ /$re/g;
    dump@res;
}

__DATA__
zeta alpha alpha beta charlie delta
zeta alpha alpha beta charlie alpha delta
```

**Output:**

```
"alpha beta"
"alpha beta"
```

Comment: This doesn't work with `zeta alpha alpha beta charlie alpha delta`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the shortest matching string that begins with `alpha` and ends with `beta`.  No "standard" regex can do this in every case, and I suspect that even Perl's various regex enhancements won't allow it (unless you jump all the way back into procedural code with `(?{...})`), because even after finding some candidate match that doesn't contain any internal `alpha`, unless the match is exactly `alpha beta`, it's still possible that a shorter match occurs further on.  For example, in `alpha charlie beta alpha beta`, how can a regex engine know to skip the first match (`alpha charlie beta`) and continue looking, so that it finds `alpha beta` later on?

So let's do it the hard way.  Assuming the string is in `$_`:

```
push @x, [pos, $&] while /alpha|beta/g;   # Find all end positions
foreach (@x) {
    if ($_->[1] eq 'alpha') {
        $lastAlpha = $_;
    } elsif (defined $lastAlpha) {
        $d = $_->[0] - $lastAlpha->[0];
        @best = ($d, $lastAlpha->[0]) if !@best || $d < $best[0];
    }
}

print substr($_, $best[1] - 5, $best[0] + 5) if @best;
```